# Correct way to connect to (a pool with) node-mongodb-native

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

With MongoDB, a suggestion was to always re-use the same database connection, and have a pool of connections to support some concurrency.

In `node-mongodb-native` `1.x` you could configure the db and server object, creating a pool like so:

```
var server = new Server(
    config.host,
    config.port,
    {
        auto_reconnect  : true,
        poolSize        : 5    // <= here is the pool
    }
);

var db = new Db(
    config.database,
    server
);

db.open(function(err, db) {
    // ...
}
```

In `2.0` they deprecated everything except `MongoClient` for connecting:

```
MongoClient.connect(URI, callback);
```

Where do I add the pool options? Do I have a pool now automatically?

With `2.1` they go a step further and suggest using a generator: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.1/reference/ecmascript6/connecting/

Is this effectively using a separate connection for every action again? Is using pools obsolete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`MongoClient.connect`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/MongoClient.html#.connect) takes an optional `options` parameter with a `server` field that lets you set the size of the connection pool:

```
const options = {
    server: {
        poolSize: 10
    }
};
MongoClient.connect(url, options, callback);
```

If you don't specify it, the default `poolSize` is 5. The `server` options are documented [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/api/Server.html).